# Oracle db query with if statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a problem with this query.

```
SELECT 
    codigo clave, descrip valor
    CASE 
       WHEN codigo IS NOT NULL 
          THEN SELECT codigo clave, codigo || ' - ' || descrip valor
       ELSE
          CASE 
             WHEN codigo IS NULL  
                SELECT codigo clave, descrip valor
          END
```

I need to concat `code` and `"-"` to something like this

- 1 - option
- 2 - option

However, in some cases the value of code is empty and it prints like this:

- option
- option

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and needed result? This would clarify your need and help people to help you.

Comment: Your code is not syntactically correct, so your question is really hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function `NVL2` to build your query. It has three parameters

```
NVL2(expr1, expr2, expr3)
```

If expr1 is NOT NULL, it returns expr2, if it is NULL, it returns expr3.

For example, `NVL2(codigo,'codigo-','')` adds a '-' only if codigo is not empty.

It things are more complicated, you could use the `CASE` statement, for instance like so:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN codigo IS NOT NULL and descrip IS NOT NULL THEN codigo||'-'||descript
         WHEN codigo IS NOT NULL and descrit IS     NULL THEN codigo
         WHEN codigo IS     NULL ANd descrip IS NOT NULL THEN descrip
         ELSE NULL
       END as myresult
 FROM mytable;
```